Windows command to clear all metadata in *.mp4 with ffmpeg
How to transform this Linux/Ubuntu command to clear out all metadata in *.mp4 files to a Windows command?
In Ubuntu it works perfectly like this:
mkdir Fertig
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "Fertig/$f"; done

Which is the equivalent command in Windows?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

See this StackOverflow answer or this StackOverflow answer. Just replace the dir command to use *.mp4 and replace the ffmpeg command with your own.

This would be the command in Windows:
In a command prompt:
md Fertig
for %a in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%a" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "Fertig\%a"

Inside a batch script:
md Fertig
for %%a in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "Fertig\%%a"


thank you ricardo! its exactly that what i need! 1 up!

@MarkusScheifinger Consider accepting the answer. See this.
